# Site cannot be installed: no matching service worker detected

Tags: javascript, json, web-applications, progressive-web-apps

Hey I am trying to program my first pwa and got the following problem:

when I start my web app I get the following error:

> Site cannot be installed: no matching service worker detected. You may need to reload the page, or check that the service worker for the current page also controls the start URL from the manifest

I think my manifest url is right because of this [link](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/samples/issues/466)

manifest.json

```
"start_url": ".",
"display": "standalone",
"orientation": "portrait",
"theme_color": "#29BDBB",
"background_color": "#29BDBB"
```

and I register my sw like this:

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
navigator.serviceWorker.register('./sw.js').then(function(reg) {
    console.log('Successfully registered service worker', reg);
}).catch(function(err) {
    console.warn('Error whilst registering service worker', err);
});
}
```

I got my sw from [here](https://github.com/IncredibleWeb/pwa-tutorial/blob/master/demo/sw.js)

So I am trying to make a simple web app which I can host with [firebase](https://shoppinglist-ecea7.firebaseapp.com/).

Whats the problem? Thanks for your help

Comment: Is protocol `https:`? Is `<link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">` included at HTML?

Comment: yeah you can find my website in the firebase link (https://shoppinglist-ecea7.firebaseapp.com/) and I added the link my manifest.json is in the same folder like my index.html and my firebase files

Comment: Was able to register `ServiceWorker` though not sure about web app portion https://plnkr.co/edit/7CneKIN60FSNa1qt3TrY?p=preview

Comment: thank you for your help finally registered my ServiceWorker too! what do you mean with app portion? and do I need the fetch() ? because I did mine without it..

Comment: `fetch()` is not necessary. Included to check if the process performed as expected. Have not previously been aware of a `manifest.json` relating to `ServiceWorker`, is the application for mobile applications only? No manifest was listed at `Application` tab

Comment: no the application should be for all platforms what's my fault?

Comment: Did not post that there was a fault. Just not familiar with the procedure, here.

Comment: okay so what is the familiar procedure? I cant find a good documentation about pwa...

Comment: How is my manifest.json related to my sw?

Comment: Apparently not at all that am aware of.

Comment: You may refer with this [link](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/samples/issues/466) which suggested to put the manifest.json on the root folder not in assets/. Once in root folder change `"start_url": "../index.php"` to `"start_url": "."`. Here's a related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43227900/web-app-banner-install).

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Place the service worker script file at the root of your website and set `start_url` to `/`, or place it wherever you want and use the `scope` property and the `Service-Worker-Allowed` HTTP header as in [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48068714/95970).

Comment: When running this command `ng add @angular/pwa --project ng-zero` where is the service worker being installed ?

Comment: @Stephane Can't you find the `ngsw-worker.js` file?
Frankly, I don't have experience with this CLI tool

Comment: @Stephane The ngsw-config.json, which builds the ngsw-worker.js is located in the root folder of your angular application

Comment: Wow, it seems a small detail, but it was not working for me without it. Now that I placed the ws in the root folder, it works perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 31):

Just in case this happens to anyone else using Angular8+. You may need to change your registration strategy to:

```
ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: environment.production, registrationStrategy: 'registerImmediately' }),
```

By default, this is set to `registerWhenStable`, which is when there are no pending tasks, things `like setTimeout()`, etc. By changing it to `registerImmediately`, it will register your service worker as soon as it possibly can.

Just thought I'd share this and add it here, as this lost me a few days trying to work it out.

Comment: @Methodician - thanks, this took me like 3/4 days to work out by debugging the Angular code

Comment: what is `ngsw-worker.js`. is it your service-worker file

Comment: @premkumar yeah, it's what Angular calls the service worker file

Comment: A link to same answer to similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60316067/angular-v8-throw-error-no-matching-service-worker-detected

Comment: @GrainedeZèle no problem :)

Answer (score 19):

The create react app service worker only goes into effect in production, so build it and serve it locally to test that the service worker is working properly.

Install serve npm first, if it isn't already: `npm i serve -g`

Then...

`npm run build`

`serve -s build`

It's also likely that once the service worker registers successully, but something like `beforeinstallprompt` might not get called.
If that's the case, publish the app using a host like firebase, which will serve the site over `https`, then try the `beforeinstallprompt` there.

Answer (score 2):

Try making the following changes:

- In **manifest.json**, the *start_url* and *scope* is set like this (or based on your preference):

  ```
    "start_url": "/",
    "scope": "."
  ```
- The **sw.js** file is located at project root, taking start_url as reference.

Answer (score 0):

for my work well updating the library "@angular/service-worker":"^7.2.15" to the version, "@angular/service-worker":"^ 8.2.3"

also placing: `ServiceWorkerModule.register ('ngsw-worker.js', {enabled: environment.production, registrationStrategy: 'registerImmediately'}),`

Comment: This is essentially the same as https://stackoverflow.com/a/61152966/1507124, if that worked consider adding this as a comment to that question

Comment: yes, but without changing the version of the service-worker it cannot, because the class does not present the attribute 'registrationStrategy'

Comment: I might be wrong because I just glanced over this, but to me, your answer looks identical to one of the already provided ones. In which case, it's inappropriate as an answer but perhaps valuable as a comment to let others know it worked for you

Answer (score -2):

one way to solve this problem is by adding a query parameter after your service worker include.
so normally you html will look like this.

```
<script src="https://example.com"></script>
```

you could modify it to look like this

```
<script src="https://example.com?v=1.1"></script>
```