# service worker doesn't work well

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, service-worker

I added the service-worker by [this tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/add-to-home-screen/#5)

In my Galaxy 6 (chrome 58.0.3029.83) it's works fine, I mean when I enter to my website, the browser ask me if I want to add the page to homepage, but in my LG6 (chomre 59.0.3071.125) it doesn't ask me, what can be the problem?

Comment: Not sure if web application is available at desktop browsers. If gather requirement correctly you could use a notification.

Comment: I tried it in Chrome, In Smartphone, Not Desktop

Comment: There was a similar recent question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45534076/site-cannot-be-installed-no-matching-service-worker-detected. Perhaps it is a chromium, chrome bug. Have you filed a bug report?