# create-react-app: Site cannot be installed: no matching service worker detected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, progressive-web-apps, manifest.json

I have this issue, i'm trying to add my React app to Homescreen.

manifest.json

```
{
  "short_name": "Ridnois",
  "name": "Ridnois - Amazing store (dev)",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "r-ico-144px.png",
      "sizes": "144x144",
      "type": "image/x-ico"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": "./index.html",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#fefefe",
  "background_color": "#fefefe"
}
```

Doing this, i get this error:

> Site cannot be installed: a 144px square PNG icon is required, but no
>   supplied icon meets this requirement

Then i tried to change the type of the icon:

```
"type":"image/png"
```

But i get this error:

> Site cannot be installed: no matching service worker detected. You may
>   need to reload the page, or check that the service worker for the
>   current page also controls the start URL from the manifest

My icon png image is 144x144px, i created the template of my app with ReactJs, my serviceWorker works fine.

Comment: To address the "no matching service worker detected" error, try the posted answer in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48078971/6143482) which is to "Site cannot be installed: no matching service worker detected. You may need to reload the page, or check that the service worker for the current page also controls the start URL from the manifest".

Comment: Can you share your directory structure?   Where is the PNG located relative to the manifest.json?

Comment: Did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Allow me to share snaps of what worked for me:

`manifest.json`

[image]

`public folder contents`

[image]

`index.html`

[image]

Seems `Chrome` wanted at least `144x144` maybe someone with more on why this worked could edit this.