# manifest and serviceworker file linkings to get Add to Homescreen for php script/website

Tags: php, html, service-worker

My Website/Script is in php and sql. I have uploaded inside a folder called New. I want to get 'Add to Homescreen' Option.

I referred this -  [Site cannot be installed: no matching service worker detected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45534076/site-cannot-be-installed-no-matching-service-worker-detected)

But when i test my manifest.json as in https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/ , i get **'No matching service worker detected. You may need to reload the page ,....'**

And my my_groups.php i have added

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    console.log("Will the service worker register?");
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('../service-worker.js')
      .then(function(reg){
        console.log("Yes, it did.");
     }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log("No it didn't. This happened:", err)
    });
 }
</script>
```

after `</body>`

and in `<head> </head>`, i have included `<link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">`

manifest.json

```
{
  "short_name": "GDD",
  "name": "GDD Play",
  "description": "For Fun.",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "gdd.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "192x192"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": "/gdd/my_groups.php",
  "background_color": "#F7F8F9",
  "theme_color": "#4A90E2",
  "display": "standalone"
}
```

sw.js ( i got this from [here](https://github.com/IncredibleWeb/pwa-tutorial/blob/master/demo/sw.js))

```
// use a cacheName for cache versioning
var cacheName = 'v1:static';

// during the install phase you usually want to cache static assets
self.addEventListener('install', function(e) {
    // once the SW is installed, go ahead and fetch the resources to make this work offline
    e.waitUntil(
        caches.open(cacheName).then(function(cache) {
            return cache.addAll([
                './',
                'includes/config.php',
                'includes/functions.php',
                'includes/top.php'

            ]).then(function() {
                self.skipWaiting();
            });
        })
    );
});

// when the browser fetches a url
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
    // either respond with the cached object or go ahead and fetch the actual url
    event.respondWith(
        caches.match(event.request).then(function(response) {
            if (response) {
                // retrieve from cache
                return response;
            }
            // fetch as normal
            return fetch(event.request);
        })
    );
});
```

serviceworker.js (It is outside the folder new)

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('new/sw.js').then(function(reg) {
        console.log('Successfully registered service worker', reg);
    }).catch(function(err) {
        console.warn('Error whilst registering service worker', err);
    });
}

window.addEventListener('online', function(e) {
    // re-sync data with server
    console.log("You are online");
    Page.hideOfflineWarning();
    Arrivals.loadData();
}, false);

window.addEventListener('offline', function(e) {
    // queue up events for server
    console.log("You are offline");
    Page.showOfflineWarning();
}, false);

// check if the user is connected
if (navigator.onLine) {
    Arrivals.loadData();
} else {
    // show offline message
    Page.showOfflineWarning();
}

// set knockout view model bindings
ko.applyBindings(Page.vm);
```

Comment: did you try serviceworker.js in new folder ?

Comment: service workers need a link in head <link rel="manifest" href="/path/to/manifest.json"> I didnt see it in your question

Comment: @Dilek : yes i tried doing that. but same issue. i have added link in head tag - `<link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">`