# Angular throw error no matching service worker detected

Tags: javascript, angular, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, angular8

I'm always get the error like below when using service worker with angular v8 which did not happend in v7

[image]

Below is my config

package.json

```
    "@angular/animations": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/pwa": "^0.900.2",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/service-worker": "~8.2.14",
```

angular.json

```
"assets": [
    "src/assets/favicon.ico",
    "src/assets",
    "src/manifest.json"
],
"configurations": {
    "production": {
        // other is ommitted
        "serviceWorker": true,
        "ngswConfigPath": "ngsw-config.json"
    }
}
```

ngsw-config.json

```
{
    "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/service-worker/config/schema.json",
    "index": "/index.html",
    "assetGroups": [
      {
        "name": "app",
        "installMode": "prefetch",
        "resources": {
          "files": [
            "/assets/favicon.ico",
            "/manifest.json",
            "/*.css",
            "/*.js"
          ]
        }
      }, {
        "name": "assets",
        "installMode": "lazy",
        "updateMode": "prefetch",
        "resources": {
          "files": [
            "/images/**"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

app.module.ts

```
 imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        ServiceWorkerModule.register("ngsw-worker.js", {
            enabled: environment.production
        })
    ],
```

index.html

```
<link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#1976d2">
```

manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "project",
    "short_name": "project",
    "theme_color": "#1976d2",
    "background_color": "#fafafa",
    "display": "standalone",
    "scope": "/",
    "start_url": "/",
    "icons": [
        {
            "src": "assets/favicon.ico",
            "sizes": "72x72",
            "type": "image/ico"
        },
        {
            "src": "assets/favicon.ico",
            "sizes": "96x96",
            "type": "image/ico"
        },
        {
            "src": "assets/favicon.ico",
            "sizes": "128x128",
            "type": "image/ico"
        },
        {
            "src": "assets/favicon.ico",
            "sizes": "144x144",
            "type": "image/ico"
        },
        {
            "src": "assets/favicon.ico",
            "sizes": "152x152",
            "type": "image/ico"
        },
        {
            "src": "assets/favicon.ico",
            "sizes": "192x192",
            "type": "image/ico"
        },
        {
            "src": "assets/favicon.ico",
            "sizes": "384x384",
            "type": "image/ico"
        },
        {
            "src": "assets/favicon.ico",
            "sizes": "512x512",
            "type": "image/ico"
        }
    ]
}
```

Please help me to point out what I have missed.

Much appriciated.

Comment: In `index.html` you link a `manifest.webmanifest` but in `ngsw-config` you reference `manifest.json`. I don't know if it will help to fix something. I am just pointing it out.

Comment: Ah sorry just a typo. I'm using json file

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I am having the exact same issue with Angular 9.0.0

Comment: @Kosso sadly not still cant find the solution :(

Comment: @TonyNgo OK. Since I asked, I discovered that a required interval on my site seems to affect the registration of the Service worker. 

So to fix it, I needed to set the `registrationStrategy` to `registerImmediately` like this: 


`ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: environment.production, registrationStrategy: 'registerImmediately' })`


By default, the Service Worker will wait until the site has 'stabilised'.

Comment: Can you post your answer. I will try it and if it work I will mark your answer as accepted @Kosso

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the issue. The network may not stable so service worker cant register. So to fix it simply add this config

```
ServiceWorkerModule.register("ngsw-worker.js", {
    enabled: environment.production,
    registrationStrategy: "registerImmediately"
})
```

Comment: Had a similar issue (seen on Chrome) with an Angular 10 PWA. This was the config I was missing. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have missed

> "/index.html"
>   "/assets/**", or maybe your assets are in separate image folder(I can't be sure until i see folder structure)
>   "/*.(eot|svg|cur|jpg|png|webp|gif|otf|ttf|woff|woff2|ani)"
>   in

```
    {
     "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/service-worker/config/schema.json",
     "index": "/index.html",
    "assetGroups": [
     {
      "name": "app",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/assets/favicon.ico",
          "/index.html",
          "/manifest.json",
          "/*.css",
          "/*.js"
        ]
       }
     }, {
      "name": "assets",
      "installMode": "lazy",
      "updateMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
           "/assets/**",
           "/*.(eot|svg|cur|jpg|png|webp|gif|otf|ttf|woff|woff2|ani)"
         ]
       }
      }
     ]
   }
```

Other than this there seems to be no difference.Although, I have tried same config as yours which was working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use

```
"ngswConfigPath": "src/ngsw-config.json",
```

instead of

```
"ngswConfigPath": "ngsw-config.json",
```

Comment: The ngsw-config.json is at the same level of angular.json file so `"ngswConfigPath": "ngsw-config.json",` is correct

Comment: Why did you move this file at the same level of angular.json? After creating dist folder did you have your ngsw-config.json inside dist?

Comment: I can't see anything wrong, but you are using `@angular/pwa` package version `^0.900.2` with Angular version `8.2.14`, can you try to upgrade from  `^0.900.2` to any version 8? I'm currently using version `^0.801.0`. Maybe there was a change from 8 to 9 which is generating your issue.