# Angular-Serviceworker: start_url does not respond with a 200 when offline

Tags: angular, firebase-hosting, lighthouse, angular-service-worker

**Versions**

- "@angular/common": "~9.0.0"
- "@angular/service-worker": "~9.0.0"

**Description**

I implemented the service-worker using `ng add @angular/pwa --project [app]` and Lighthouse would recognise the web-app as a PWA.
Suddenly, after one deploy to Firebase hosting the "install" notification wasn´t popping up, so I checked the dev-console.

The manifest was still showing up as usual:

[image]

But nothing was being cached:

[image]

When running a Lighthouse-Audit, I get following error:

```
start_url does not respond with a 200 when offline
```

**ngsw-config.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/service-worker/config/schema.json",
  "index": "/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [
    {
      "name": "app",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/favicon.ico",
          "/index.html",
          "/manifest.webmanifest",
          "/*.css",
          "/*.js"
        ]
      }
    }, {
      "name": "assets",
      "installMode": "lazy",
      "updateMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/assets/**",
          "/*.(eot|svg|cur|jpg|png|webp|gif|otf|ttf|woff|woff2|ani)"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**manifest.webmanifest**

```
{
  "name": "App",
  "short_name": "App",
  "theme_color": "#5787b2",
  "background_color": "#fafafa",
  "display": "standalone",
  "scope": "/",
  "start_url": "/",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-192x192.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-512x512.png",
      "sizes": "512x512",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I found the solution to my problem in this comment to a similar problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61152966/8581106

In `app.module.ts` add `registrationStrategy: 'registerImmediately'` to the registration of the ServiceWorker like this:

```
ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: env.production, registrationStrategy: 'registerImmediately' }),
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had the following in my app.module imports:

```
ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: environment.production })
```

Except the prod variable was returning `false` because the environment being used was not --prod. Make sure `env.production` is actually returning "true" where it's supposed to. A good place to start is in `package.json` in "scripts". Check the command is running `--configuration=prod-env` or however you've got it configured.